# curl returns 302 found registering Telegram method

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I have this PHP code to register a bot to Telegram:

```
<?php

$WEBHOOK_URL = 'https://.../exec.php';
$BOT_TOKEN = 'botMyToken';

$API_URL = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . $BOT_TOKEN .'/';
$method = 'setWebhook';
$params = array('url' => $WEBHOOK_URL);
$url = $API_URL . $method. '?' . http_build_query($params);
$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
$result = curl_exec($handle);
print_r($result);

?>
```

Once called from the browser address bar, this should return:

```
{"ok":true,"result":true,"description":"Webhook was set"}
```

Instead, I get a `302 Found` and nothing else.

I suppose this could be a `curl` issue, but I can't understand how and if it is possible to overcome it. I even tried adding:

```
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true)
```

but with no luck.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It seems you forgot a slash "/' after "bot": `'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . $BOT_TOKEN .'/';`

Comment: Felippe Duarte, why do I need to add a "/"? I have not found this in the docs

Comment: Just checked docs, your url seems ok. If you put the address directly into your browser address bar, it works?

Comment: Felippe Duarte, I found what it was (thanks for pointing my eyes to the "bot" area of the URL): the Telegram token starts with 'bot' but I added it two times (in the $BOT_TOKEN variable and in the $API_URL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what it was: the Telegram token starts with 'bot' but I added it two times (in the $BOT_TOKEN variable and in the $API_URL)